# How to save date format in sql database

Tags: database, knex.js

I am trying to save this date format in my sql database but getting an error. please what am I doing wrong?

```
return knex.schema.createTable("adverts", (table) => {
      table.increments(); 
      table.string("advertName", 128).notNullable();
      table.string("websiteUrl", 128).notNullable();
      table.string("country", 128).notNullable();
      table.string("tags", 128).notNullable();
      table.integer("days", 128).notNullable();
      table.string("number", 128).notNullable();
      table.date()("dateString", 128).notNullable();
    });
  }
```

Comment: A good tip, mention the technologies regarding your question, and the error message(s) itself.

Comment: error message
TypeError: table.date(...) is not a function

i am using nodejs and knex

Comment: depends on database.